# How to resize 1000x1000 image into 200x300 image without distorting the aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

The images are actually in 1000x1000 resolution. I want to display the images in 200x300 resolution without distorting the aspect ratio.

How can I achieve this?

Currently I used this method,

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url().$pl['product_image'];?>" 
                             style="width:200px;min-height:300px; max-height:300px;"/>
```

Comment: So you want to change the aspect ratio without changing the aspect ratio?

Comment: you could resize to 200x200 and add 50px up and down of white space to make up for the missing 100px

Comment: ummm.... photoshop.... and recreate one... that is 200*300

Comment: you can do one of the following: 1) actually change aspect ratio 2) crop the image 3) add padding to the top/bottom

Comment: From 1000x1000 to 200x300, actually you're changing the aspect ratio. You could resize to 200x200 and center the image in your container.

Comment: it's really funny, most ppl don't understand aspect ration.  more often enough my client want to change a vertical design to horizontal,  they think it's just matter of dragging it on the screen.  take 2 second... yeah right!

Comment: I think OP wants the same effect than `background-size: cover` except with an img element...

Answer (score 2):

Put your images as background-images of a div rather than putting them as `img` tags.

```
<div style="background: url(http://waveilk.com/product_images/0cd666329a45121a3550611f9496e66fKMTWS00064-1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%; width: 200px; height: 300px; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

Using your PHP code, this would become

```
<div style="background: url(<?php echo base_url().$pl['product_image'];?>) no-repeat 50% 50%; width: 200px; height: 300px; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1n5pdcwx/

Comment: Downside: bad semantix